# How to prove this q-binomial identity?

Tags: combinatorics

Need to show: ${2n\choose n}_q$ $\frac{1}{(n+1)_q}$ is a polynomial of q with positive coefficients. My beginning logistics is to show that $2n \choose n$ $ = \sum_{j = 0}^n q^{j^2}*{2n \choose j}^2_q$ and then to show that $\frac{{2n \choose j}^2_q}{(n+1)_q}$ is some constant free of q, but the equation was just messed up and I don't know how to further prove it. Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Show that

$$
\frac1{(n+1)_q}\binom{2n}{n}_q=\binom{2n}{n}_q-q\binom{2n}{n-1}_q.
$$